# How do you disable "/controlpanel" directory redirect to :2083 in WHM?

Tags: apache, redirect, cpanel, whm

I've used WHM and cpanel for years but recently noticed that after an update the "/controlpanel" directory has been automatically added allowing domain.com/controlpanel to redirect to domain.com:2083

How do you disable this redirect that is public facing?

Comment: I've noticed this on multiple hosts. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Ran a Veracode dynamic scan and found it, but wanted to stop it from appearing as a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/controlpanel` and `/securecontrolpanel` are controlled by `ScriptAliasMatch` in `httpd.conf` which cannot by modified directly as WHM/cPanel will rebuild it again as it where before the manual modifications. So it will be better if modifications done through one of the following options:

> SSH access is needed to apply any one of these

1. Modify the yaml file which used in the rebuild apache configuration process, the file can be found under `/var/cpanel/conf/apache/local` or `/var/cpanel/conf/apache/main` then rebuild apache configuration by running `/scripts/rebuildhttpdconf` then restart apache by running `/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_httpd`
2. Modify the template file which used to parse the previous yaml file in order to generate the configuration file. First copy this file `/var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/ea4_main.default` to `/var/cpanel/templates/apache2_4/ea4_main.local` then start modifying it then rebuild and restart apache.

And my vote goes to the first option to keep it clean and simple as possible but it worth knowing both ways so you can extend the functionality as much as you can.

For more details:

- [Apache Global Configuration docs](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/78Docs/Global+Configuration)
- [Apache Custom Templates docs](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA4/Custom+Templates)